# How do I Type a dict with a null key value?

Tags: python, typeddict

Below is a snippet of a JSON file I'm trying to work with;

```json
{
    "": {
        "0": {
            "1874900": {
                "0": "Fri, 27 May 2022 14:06:00 GMT",
                "0x": "1660211676",
                "2": "Mon, 09 May 2022 11:15:24 GMT",
                "2x": "1660211706",
                "1": "Mon, 09 May 2022 11:14:02 GMT",
                "1x": "1660211641",
                "3": "Mon, 09 May 2022 11:12:36 GMT",
                "3x": "1660211661",
                "icon": "611ef8ba927cc6cbcdeb6ff954cb059539a28ab2",
                "4x": "1967453026",
                "5": "Fri, 27 May 2022 15:45:26 GMT",
                "5x": "1660211706",
                "change": "15628780",
                "v": "3"
            },
            "8680": {
                "change": "11703200",
                "v": "3"
            },
            "851470": {
                "change": "15318595",
                "v": "3"
            }
        },
        "1":{
            "594602": {
                "change": "13682071",
                "v": "3"
            },
            "594596": {
                "change": "13682071",
                "v": "3"
            },
            "594600": {
                "change": "13682071",
                "v": "3"
            },
            "594601": {
                "change": "13682071",
                "v": "3"
            },
            "594595": {
                "change": "13682071",
                "v": "3"
            },
            "2093200": {
                "3": "Fri, 29 Jul 2022 12:11:31 GMT",
                "3x": "1660219952",
                "change": "15629992",
                "v": "3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a TypedDict class for this schema but I'm falling at the first hurdle as I can't figure out how to handle the root key of "".

Does anyone know how I would go about Typing this key?

Comment: Can you delete that key?

Comment: This ain't no Hogwarts fam

Comment: You can do it with a TypedDict instance, but not a TypedDict class.

Comment: Is it always just that one empty key? Why don't you just extract the value of that key, and use a TypedDict for its value?

Comment: It's very strange that the API returns JSON like this. Are you sure you're not doing something that's creating the empty key unnecessarily?

Comment: @Barmar I can't even do it as an instance; "Names within a TypedDict cannot be empty".

Comment: It's not from an API - it's a local file generated by an installed application.

Comment: Can you fix that application? What's the point of a key that's always the same empty string?

Comment: And how will you type the elements that have numeric keys. None of this looks like it's amenable to TypedDict, because the keys are all dynamic.

Comment: I think what I might do is replace "" with "BLANK" when opening the file and type that and then replace it back to "" when saving as there are nested blanks in the file too...

Comment: Fixing it isn't really an option, it's made by Valve haha..

Comment: this just seems to be a horrible data structure. Sequential numeric keys should be a list, not a dict.

Comment: I'm just going to go with dict[str,Any] I think... You're right, even skipping that blank key is a nightmare with the numerical keys. EDIT: actually dict[str,str|dict|int] will cover it as they seem to be the only types in the file.

Comment: That isn't null, that is an empty string. Which is a rather strange key TBQH